# Calculation detail of Batch Normalization

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, normalization, batch-normalization

I am implementing the BN algorithm in my CNN model using C++. But I am very confused because of its calculation of mean and standard deviation. Let's see the below pictures.

[image: BN computation fig]

[image: BN algorithm equation]

As far as I know, each pixel mean value has to be computed. but I don't know which of the equations is correct.

Let's assume that the BN's input is [B, H, W], where B is the batch size, (H, W) is the feature map size (Suppose to [3,2,2]).

1. Mean of all pixels in one image

   ([0,0,0]+[0,0,1]+[0,1,0]+[0,1,1])/4

Mini-batch means are scalar

2. Mean of the same location's pixel in multiple images (image num = batch num )

   ([0,0,0]+[1,0,0]+[2,0,0])/3 ,
     ([0,0,1]+[1,0,1]+[2,0,1])/3 ,
     ([0,1,0]+[1,1,0]+[2,1,0])/3 ,
     ([0,1,1]+[1,1,1]+[2,1,1])/3 )

Mini-batch means are an array

What calculation is right?

Answer (score 0):

Neither is correct.  Method 1 merely normalizes each image; it has nothing to do with the batch as a whole.  Method 2 will almost certainly damage your training, as it decouples adjacent pixels from one another.

You need to compute the mean and variance of *all* pixels in the batch.  Then normalize each pixel with the `scale and shift` equation using those batch statistics.